# PHP: How to concatenate a reference to string variable?

Tags: php, string, reference, concatenation

In the following snippet of PHP the `$phrases` needs to reflect the change made in `$greeting`. How can this be achieved?

```
$greeting = "Hello!";

$phrases = array('greeting' => $greeting . " Glad to see you.");
echo $phrases['greeting'];
```

*`Hello! Glad to see you.`*

```
$greeting = "How are you?";
echo $phrases['greeting'];
```

*`Hello! Glad to see you.`*

Note, that even after the value of  `$greeting` variable changed, the array remained unchanged (which is normally an expected behavior, since the value of `$greeting` var is passed by value).

In order to make array to do change, I tried to use references to variables, but they don't seem to work with concatenation operator `.`.

Appreciate if anyone could suggest a quick solution to this..

Comment: I believe you cant do this the way you want, because the array gets 'built' up there. To reflect the change, you may have to write another function or something that can refresh the array contents.

Comment: How about having a class with greeting as a property ? may not be a quick solution though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a dynamic string variable, which is not possible in php.

You need to use a function.

A method which is probably closest to your code is storing as array with reference and using implode:

```
$greeting = "Hello!";

$phrases = array(&$greeting," Glad to see you.");
echo implode($phrases);

$greeting = "Hi!";
echo implode($phrases);
```

Edit: removed two other possible methods

Comment: Thanks, Billy. This is somewhat close to what I intended. However I'm still not sure how to best use it with a deep nested array.

Answer (score 2):

most common way to add placeholders to your strings would be [printf()](http://php.net/printf)

```
$phrases = array('greeting' => "%s Glad to see you.");

$greeting = "Hello!";
printf($phrases['greeting'],$greeting);
$greeting = "How are you?";
printf($phrases['greeting'],$greeting);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, your solution only covers printing part. What if later we need to reassign `$phrases['greeting']` to another variable   e.g. `$x = $phrases['greeting']`?

Comment: OP wants the changes to be reflected in the array, when he changes `$phrases['greeting']` in a (usual) separate statement.

Comment: Thrustmaster, exactly. I need the changes be seen in array.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use the &.

Example:

```
$a = 'a';
$b = array(&$a);
$a = 'b';
print_r($b);
```

Prints:

> Array ( [0] => b )

**Edit**: You can not use the &-symbol when concatenating strings. You should redefine the whole variable or use printf or something (but I recommend you to redefine the whole variable.)

Answer (score 0):

So you want that your value in the `$pharses` array changes everytime you change the value of `$greeting`? This is not possible, since when you create string, a "string-object" is created, that is a reference to a certain part in memory where the value of it is hardcoded and will never be changed.

You would have to write a function, like

```
function getPhrase(which) {
   // do concatenation using $greeting
}
```

which you have to call whenever you want to output a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later..
You could acheave the same with:

```
$greeting = "Hello!";

$phrases = array('greeting' => function() use (&$greeting) {
                return $greeting." Glad to see you.";
            });

echo call_user_func($phrases['greeting']);

$greeting = "Oh NOOO!";
echo call_user_func($phrases['greeting']);
```